# a SWT control refuses to "grab excess vertical space"

Tags: eclipse, swt, grid-layout

The case is that the TopTaskGroup(left one) can "grab excess vertical space" while resizing window[image], but the NewTaskGroup(the right one), after adding a TooBar on it(see the `createAddBtnOnGroup` method), it doesn't grow as you resize the window. Why is that?

(I have a shell instance with 2-column GridLayout)

[image]

Code is here:

```
private void createTaskWidgets() {
    createTopTaskGroup();
    createNewTaskGroup();
}

private void createTopTaskGroup() {
    Group topTasksGroup = new Group(shell, SWT.SHADOW_NONE);
    topTasksGroup.setText(TaskConsts.TOP_TASK_LIST);

    topTasksTable = new TaskTable(topTasksGroup, TaskTable.SORT_BY_VOTES, iteration, this);
    topTasksTable.setLayoutData(getTableGridData() );

    topTasksGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout() );
    topTasksGroup.setLayoutData(getTableGridData() );
    topTasksGroup.pack();
}

private void createNewTaskGroup() {
    Group newTasksGroup = new Group(shell, SWT.SHADOW_NONE);
    newTasksGroup.setText(TaskConsts.NEW_TASK_LIST);

    newTasksTable = new TaskTable(newTasksGroup, TaskTable.SORT_BY_CREATION_TIME, iteration, this);
    topTasksTable.setLayoutData(getTableGridData() );

    ToolBar actionToolBar = createAddBtnOnGroup(newTasksGroup);

    newTasksGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout() );
    newTasksGroup.setLayoutData(getTableGridData() );
    newTasksGroup.layout();
    newTasksGroup.pack();

    // set actionToolBar's location to newTasksGroup's right-top position
    actionToolBar.setLocation(
            newTasksGroup.getLocation().x + newTasksGroup.getSize().x
                    - actionToolBar.getSize().x - 5,
            newTasksGroup.getLocation().y - 2);
}

private GridData getTableGridData() {
    GridData gridData = new GridData(0, SWT.FILL, false, true);
    return gridData;
}

private ToolBar createAddBtnOnGroup(Group newTasksGroup) {
    ToolBar actionToolBar = new ToolBar(newTasksGroup, SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.RIGHT);

    addTaskToolItem = new ToolItem(actionToolBar, SWT.PUSH | SWT.RIGHT);
    addTaskToolItem.setImage(new Image(display, TaskConsts.ICON_PLUS));

    final MainWindow mainWindow = this;
    addTaskToolItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            new CreateTask(getShell(), mainWindow);
        }
    });

    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.exclude = true;
    actionToolBar.setLayoutData(gridData);

    actionToolBar.pack();

    return actionToolBar;
}

private void organize() {
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    shell.setLayout(gridLayout);
    shell.pack();
}
```

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your excellent problem description!

It seems to me that this is a simple copy-paste bug.

The fourth line in your *createNewTaskGroup*  method should not be

```
topTasksTable.setLayoutData(getTableGridData() );
```

but

```
newTasksTable.setLayoutData(getTableGridData() );
```

Comment: any idea for refactoring? I'm, like, 70% convinced that it should be refactored to omit duplicated code. But I'm still thinking the amount of the duplicated code is relative small...and there is no obvious way to refactor it~